# Facebook API & CakePHP

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, cakephp

I'm integrating the Facebook API (PHP-SDK) with CakePHP and I know that there exist a few integrations already but I'm stubborn enough to do this on my own. My question is, providing the fact that I have a FacebookController with a few methods, such as:

```
function one() {
//code
}
function two() {
//code
}
function three() {
//code
}
```

I have to add the following inside all of my functions:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'appID',
'secret' => 'secret',
));
```

which seems to be bad practice and massive code-repetition. Can I make the $facebook variable 'global', and therefore be able to access it throughout all the methods in my controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign in a private variable in beforeFilter function.

```
private $facebookData = array();

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->facebookData = new Facebook(array(
                              'appId'  => 'appID',
                              'secret' => 'secret',
                          ));
}
```

Than you can access in any method of that controller eg:

```
function one() {
 print_r($this->facebookData);
}
```

Comment: One more question -- what if I'd like to have this $facebookData array throughout multiple CakePHP controllers - do you believe it's possible? I'm new to CakePHP and I'm sort of learning on the go...

Comment: Yes it possible. You can use session in such case.

Comment: Rikesh, would you be able to elaborate on that a bit for me?

Comment: Read how to use [session](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html). You will get an better idea.